# Azure Web App with ADFS/OWIN (Intermittent MSIS7043: UpdateLoopDetectionCookie)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, owin, azure-web-app-service, adfs

I followed [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-lob-application-adfs/) for setting up an Azure Web App w/ADFS (using OWIN instead of WIF) adding this to an existing MVC3 web app. Authentication works normal locally but after deploying to an Azure Web App I'm getting intermittent MSIS7042 UpdateLoopDetectionCookie errors (when accessing just the root site, not [Authorize] tagged code). The Relying Party Trust does not have an additional certificate configured.  The RPTs for local/azure are configured with the exact same claims.

I've worked with ADFS (WIF) and Azure Cloud Services before and had to use a custom RSA SecurityTokenHandler to keep the cookie/token encryption consistent across sessions (X509 Cert signing instead of Machine Key). The MS article didn’t mention needing this but after getting the first few STS authentication loops I thought this might be the issue.   I’ve implemented this in OWIN using a custom X509DataProtectionProvider.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.SetDataProtectionProvider(new X509DataProtectionProvider("AppName") );
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(480)
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = metadata,
                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

No matter what I try I keep getting the loop detection exception from ADFS.  At this point I might go back to WIF instead.  Just don't want to leave this issue hanging.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '5' seconds. Contact your administrator for details. 
at          Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.UpdateLoopDetectionCookie()   
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SendSignInResponse(MSISSignInResponse response)
```

Comment: Try https in URL rather than http